# concatenate the string with different seprator in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

for example i have

| id | shape |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | square |
| 1 | circle |
| 1 | triangle |
| 2 | square |
| 2 | circle |
| 2 | triangle |
| 2 | rectangle |

and i want

| ID | Shape |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | square AND circle OR triangle |
| 2 | square OR circle AND triangle AND rectangle |

this way i want to use  'AND' and 'OR' as a seprator how can i use as a seprator from these two without using '||' concatination.

i tried array_to_string(array_agg(shape),'AND') but it takes only one seprator 'AND' so how can i get the required output?

Comment: Please explain the logic for the separator you want.

Comment: i have one condition in a parts by adding the 'AND' and 'OR' i am trying to make that condition as one condition. (is that clear to you now?)

Comment: Can you explain the logic of when you need "AND" and when you need "OR"?

Comment: Explain the logic behind **Why** id=1 gets `square AND circle OR triangle` where as id=2 gets `square OR circle ...` when both have the same 2 leading shapes.  Further is there a different result pattern  when leading shapes are different? Is there a different result pattern when the number of shapes per id is different.  Why are you trying to avoid the concatenation operator (||)  and does this also extent to the concatenation function (concat)?